# Weird segmentation fault (difference between arrays and pointers ?)

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

i cant see why i'm getting segmentation fault from this code and somehow when i use arrays instead of pointers it works, i would be happy if anyone can make me understand this.

```
void main() {
   char *str = "example string";
   wrapChrInStr(str, 'a');
}

void wrapChrInStr(char *str, unsigned char chr) {
   char *ptr = str;
   char c;

   while((c = *ptr)) {
       if(c != chr) {
           *str = c;
           str++;
           ptr++;
       } else {
           ptr++;
       }
   }
   *str = '\0';
}
```

Comment: `str` is pointing to read only memory, `*str = '\0';` will fail with segfault. You can declare `str` as `char str[] = "..."` or with a fixed size `char str[50] = "...."`

Comment: thank you for your answer. Why its read only can you explain please ?

Comment: Because `"example string"` is a [string literal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_literal) and they usually are stored in a read-only section.

Comment: Thank you. I'm doing a lot of c programming and its really weird that i never faced that before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Thank you. I'm doing a lot of c programming and its really weird that i never faced that before.

Probably because you don't realize that there are different ways of storing a
C-String. You may have been lucky enough never to have encountered a segfault
because of this.

**String literals**

A string literal is declared with double quotation marks, e.g.

```
"hello world"
```

This string is usually stored in a read-only section. When using string
literals, it's best to declare the variables with a `const` like this:

```
const char *str = "hello world";
```

With this you know that `str` is pointing to read-only memory location and you cannot
manipulate the contents of the string. In fact, if you do this:

```
const char *str = "hello world";
str[0] = 'H';
// or the equivalent
*str = 'H'
```

the compiler will return an error like this:

```
a.c:5:5: error: assignment of read-only location ‘*str’
```

which I found very helpful, because you cannot accidentally manipulate the
contents pointed to by `str`.

**Arrays**

If you need to manipulate the contents of a string, then you need to store the
string in an array, e.g.

```
char str[] = "hello word";
```

In this case the compiler knows that the string literal has 10 characters and reserves 11 bytes (1 byte for `'\0'` - the terminating byte) for `str` and initializes the array with
the contents of the string literal.

Here you can do stuff like

```
str[0] = 'H'
```

but you cannot access beyond the 11th byte.

You can also declare an array with a fixed size. In this case the size must be
at least the same as the length+1 of the string literal.

```
char str[11] = "Hello world";
```

If you declare less space (`char str[3] = "hello world";` for example),
your compiler will warn you with something like this

```
a.c:4:14: warning: initializer-string for array of chars is too long
```

but I'm not sure what happens if you execute the code anyway. I think this is a case of undefined behaviour
and that means: anything can happen.

Personally, I usually declare my string without a fixed size, unless there is
a reason for having a fixed size.

Comment: "In this case the size must be at least the same as the length+1 of the string literal."  - the +1 does not apply, you even showed this in your example (there are 11 nonzero characters in the initializer of `char str[11]`)

Comment: Yeah but for a proper program its true. Because a string without termination character would cause a undefined behaviour